How to Use the Vertex API With Long Text Prompts
Overview
I've been using the Vertex API relatively successfully for the past few months, but I've noticed that when the text part of your prompt becomes extremely long, for example, 130,000 characters or so, the API seems to malfunction.
Implementation Details

Gemini 1.5 Pro as the llm
React front-end
Firebase / Firestore / Cloud Functions as the back-end

API Infrastructure
I've tried two approaches to integrating with Vertex:

Using the vertexai-preview package that ships with firebase
Using the VertexAI NodeJS package in a cloud function with increased (1 GB) memory allocation and a longer (120 sec) max runtime

Package Structure
All of my calls to Vertex follow the documentation's pattern, where the "files" sent to the llm are included via a Cloud Storage URI and the text parts of the prompt are text parts. Like this:
async function multiPartContent() {
    const filePart = {fileData: {fileUri: "gs://generativeai-downloads/images/scones.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg"}};
    const textPart = {text: 'What is this picture about?'};
    const request = {
        contents: [{role: 'user', parts: [textPart, filePart]}],
      };
    const streamingResult = await generativeVisionModel.generateContentStream(request);
    for await (const item of streamingResult.stream) {
      console.log('stream chunk: ', JSON.stringify(item));
    }
    const aggregatedResponse = await streamingResult.response;
    console.log(aggregatedResponse.candidates[0].content);
}

In my case, I am using the generateContentStream approach.
Expected Behavior
Given the massive context window, I expect to be able to send lots of information to the llm, then get a response back.
Observed Behavior
vertexai-preview client-side package
When using the vertexai-preview package, I get a Firebase Error with no message property as I start pushing the requests, including more files and text.
I can confirm that my usage is nowhere near the 2m token context window. Usually, these heavier requests are around 200k tokens.
VertexAI server-side approach
Here's a relevant code block from my Cloud Function:
const req = {
      contents: [{ role: "user", parts }],
    };

    console.log(`Initiating content generation for docId: ${docId}`);
    const streamingResp = await generativeModel.generateContentStream(req);

This logic will work for non-large requests, but when there's a heavier request, it will fail. In the cloud logs, I'll see the "Initiating content generation" and, even though I'm catching the errors in my code (the block you see is inside a try / catch block), I don't see any additional cloud logs. The process literally just poof ends.
Some things I've tried
Chunking the text parts
I've tried to convert long text strings into multiple smaller (e.g. ~50k character) text parts. So, the parts I send the llm have, for example:

3 fileUri parts
3 text parts

This didn't work at all.
Sending the long text part as a fileUri part
I've tried converting long text strings into stored plain text files, then sending them as fileUri parts.
This approach does seem to improve reliability. Here, I run into something of a prompt engineering problem, because the prompt actually is in the now-stored text file that I've sent to the LLM.
Summary
Overall, I'm finding it difficult to work with the Vertex API with these larger requests. The Vertex API claims to be able to process these heavy requests, but I'm just finding that as I make these higher-token requests the API completely fails with errors that are non-descriptive.

I never see any max memory errors
I never see any function run time errors
I never see any errors talking about the length of the text part of my prompt (also, if you happen to know what, if any, limitations there are on the text part of Vertex prompts, please let me know)

I'd love to know how to approach this.

Handling Large Requests with Vertex AI: Lessons Learned
After extensive testing, I discovered several key insights about working with Vertex AI for large-scale AI operations. Here's what I learned and how I solved it:
The Problem with Vertex AI Preview Package
The vertexai-preview package, while convenient for simple implementations, has significant limitations when handling:

Large prompts (100K+ characters)
Complex data structures
Long-running operations
High memory requirements

The Solution: Architecture Changes
1. Move Away from Direct Client-Server Connection
Instead of this:
// Client directly waiting for AI response
const response = await vertexai.generateContent(prompt);

Use this pattern:
// Client
// 1. Initialize request
const requestId = await initiateAIProcess(prompt);
// 2. Listen for updates
onSnapshot(doc(db, 'aiResponses', requestId), (snapshot) => {
  const response = snapshot.data();
  if (response.status === 'complete') {
    // Handle completion
  }
});

// Server
exports.processAIRequest = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,  // 9 minutes
    memory: '1GB'
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data) => {
    // Process AI request
    // Write results to Firestore
});

2. Use Custom Cloud Functions
Rather than relying on the Preview package's default function configuration:

Configure higher memory allocation (1GB+)
Set longer timeout periods (5+ minutes)
Enable background processing

3. Implement Progress Tracking
For long-running operations:

Store request state in Firestore
Update progress incrementally
Allow client to reconnect and resume monitoring

Key Takeaways

The Vertex AI Preview package is best suited for:

Simple AI integrations
Quick response requirements
Limited data processing


For production applications, especially those handling large amounts of data:

Use custom Cloud Functions
Implement asynchronous processing
Design for potential disconnections
Monitor and handle timeouts explicitly


Consider breaking large requests into smaller, manageable chunks if possible


This approach has proven much more reliable for handling complex AI operations with large datasets.
